# Exercise $2.9.7$ of Kumaresan's Differential Geometry and Lie Groups .

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields, submanifold

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Let $S$ be the set of all lines through $(0,y)$ parallel to $x-$axis where $y \in \mathbb R-\mathbb Q$ . Is it an integral submanifold for $V=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}?$

$\mathbf {My \  approach}:$ Take $p=(0,√2)\in S$ ,the integral curve of $V$ via $p$  is $\{(t,√2)| t\in \mathbb R\}.$

S is disconnected $1$-dimensional manifold .

Now, I can't see why $S$ can't be an integral submanifold of $V$ so I think $S$ will be .

A small hint is required, thanks in advance .

Comment: The statement is miswritten. All lines?

Comment: Sorry; now corrected .

Comment: What is the precise definition of integral submanifold?

Comment: An immersed submanifold $S$ is said to be integral submanifold  for distribution $D$ if $T_zS=D_z$ for all $z\in S.$

Comment: Can you not answer your own question definitively now?

Comment: I resign. Go ask your instructor.